# Dymos: Strange behavior with derivatives when certain state variables are set as zeros

Tags: openmdao

I'm trying to replicate the optimization problem solved in this paper using Dymos:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877705812045651

The model consists of a system of ODE's (Eq's 1-4 in the paper) and I was ablel to run the model without any issue. But when I ran an optimization problem involving design variables `k1, k2, c1, and c2`, I encountered the following issue:

```
...openmdao/core/total_jac.py:1596: DerivativesWarning:Design variables [('traj.phase0.parameters:k1', inds=[0]), ('traj.phase0.parameters:k2', inds=[0]), ('traj.phase0.parameters:c1', inds=[0]), ('traj.phase0.parameters:c2', inds=[0])] have no impact on the constraints or objective.
```

The strange thing is this only happens when a couple of the state variables, namely `theta` and `theta_dot`, are assigned initial values of zeros (via `set_value()`). If I assign any non-zero value, this issue doesn't come up.

I used the scaling report function and checked that the sensitivities with respect to the design variables are indeed all zero if the initial `theta` and `theta_dot` values are zero. On the other hand, the sensitivities are properly computed if the initial `theta` and `theta_dot` values are non-zero.

(Note that I can assign zero initial values to other state variables and this issue doesn't come up.)

I was wondering if what could cause this issue?

Comment: Is the potentially an issue with collocation? If you use an explicit shooting approach it may exhibit the expected behavior.  If all the states are zero then is the system at equilibrium then those parameters may have no impact.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I tried explicit shooting...
```NotImplementedError: cannot yet constrain/optimize an ODE output using explicit shooting```

FYI, I've tried setting the initial values for theta and theta_dot as low as I can and the issue comes up when their values are 1e-19 or lower.

Comment: I need to look at the equations more closely but I'm wondering if this is a stationary point in the optimization problem.  If the sensitivities are zero there then the optimizer may see equal benefit in pushing the design variables in either direction.  Do you have an example of the code available?